# Skip HTML tags in JSON Response of walmart open APIs

Tags: node.js, json, express, walmart-api

How can we get a response without escaped HTML tags from Walmart open API's

Example:
When using search API the sample response is

```
{
    "query": "ipod",
    "sort": "relevance",
    "responseGroup": "base",
    "totalResults": 257,
    "start": 1,
    "numItems": 10,
    "items": [{
        "itemId": 42608125,
        "parentItemId": 42608125,
        "name": "Apple iPod touch 32GB",
        "msrp": 247.0,
        "upc": "888462353151",
        "categoryPath": "Electronics/Portable Audio/Apple iPods/iPod Touch",
        "shortDescription": "The Apple iPod Touch 32GB is loaded with features. It is the ideal solution for carrying your music collection in your pocket. The device comes in five stunning colors, giving you plenty of options to choose from. Listen to your favorite songs from Apple Music and iTunes. It also offers the ultimate mobile gaming experience for versatility,
        "longDescription": **"&lt;b&gt;&lt;br&gt;Apple iPod touch 32GB:&lt;/b&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;Memory: 32 GB&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Portable iPod touch has touchscreen controls&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Bluetooth capable&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Wireless LAN&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Battery is built-in&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;4&quot; retina display&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;1080p HD video recording&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Up to 40 hours audio playback&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;8-hour video&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;8 Megapixel camera&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Includes ear buds and charging cable&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Available in Blue, Gold, Pink, White and Silver and Space Gray&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;**",
}
```

In the JSON response mentioned above, I want to skip the HTML tags while getting the response.

Comment: What do you mean by skip?

Comment: I don't want HTML tags in the response@Utkanos
 If you see the above example in the JSON object for longDescription value there are HTML tags available. I don't need these html tags

Comment: Do you want to remove just the tags, or the content within them also?

Comment: Just remove tags, I need content to render on my application

Answer (score 0):

This simple function should decode html entities and then strip html tags from the text you get from that API:

```
function stripHtmlEntities(str) {
    let decodedHtml = decodeEntities(str);
    let el = document.createElement('span');
    el.innerHTML = decodedHtml;
    return el.textContent || el.innerText;
}
```

**UPDATE**: to work with `node.js`, where you do not have a DOM, you should do something like this:

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const dom = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html>`);
const document = dom.window.document;
```

Of course this solution is not so slick as it is for Javascript, for sure you can find better ways to strip HTML... :-)

Comment: I am using nodejs, I think there is no document object available.

Comment: You're right, sorry, didn't notice the `node.js` tag... :-(
Updating my answer to target `node.js`...

Answer (score 0):

you can use below function to remove html tags
`function strip_html_tags(str)
{
   if (!str)
       return;
  else
  str = str.toString();
  return str.replace(/&lt;[^&gt;]*&gt;/g, '');
}`